# Titles With First Letters As Capitals vs Regular titles?

Tags: video, title

I just saw a video with the title:

> Elon Musk Explains His Thoughts On Warren Buffet | Joe Rogan Podcast
> Highlights

And i'm wondering, why did the author use a first letter of each word as capital?

It could've been written as follows but somehow author preffered the first option:

> Elon Musk explains his thoughts on Warren Buffet | Joe Rogan podcast
> highlights

Does the first option gain more attention or is there some other scientific reason behind this? Or is it just a preference thing?

Answer (score 7):

The writing style of the title is referred to as title case or headline case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case

The second example is not in the title case writing style.

Comment: This is the particularly tedious part of report writing, when you realise capitalisation inconsistencies have slipped in.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article is well worth a look, as it demonstrates that the example is an extreme form of title case, probably done by machine. A more conventional version would have the "on", and maybe even "his".

Comment: I've never seen a good reason for capitalising only _some_ of the words.  (I suspect that the practice derives from the days when all nouns were capitalised as a matter of course.)  Conversely, there are many cases when capitalising all of them can remove ambiguity: consider the difference between Pride and Prejudice and Pride And Prejudice.  I've been capitalising every word of titles for ages, and seen only benefits.

Comment: So is it just a preference or is there any reason of using this style over others?
I'd like to start my new youtube channel, and I'd like to set up some design guidelines beforehand, so this thing bothers me right now 

Comment: Not a preference.  It is a writing style, that is, several books have been published that inform readers on the appropriate way to write, such as, Strunk and White's "Elements of Style" and the "Chicago Manual of Style."  The title case is likely in both.  The books may have the same title case rules or there may be minor differences in the rules.

Answer (score -3):

Just in my opinion,  i think the reason they use capital letter for each first letter. It is to prevent the misleading title if typo of spacing occurs, take this example below:

[image]

Clearly we can see the functionality here, it is to remove the accidental ambiguities whether is **Elon Muskex** / **Elon Musk Explains**, **Joe Roganpod** / **Joe Rogan podcast**.

That's the best answer i can find.

Comment: What?! This is certainly not the reason for title casing.

Comment: Why would spacing problems occur?

Comment: If there is no typo of spacing but a typo of capitalization how would you read it?